# People detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, raspberry-pi, object-detection

I need to get coordinates of people in the room using Raspberry Pi and a web cam hanged to the ceiling. I've tried some OpenCV algorithms but I am not really familiar with this framework.

Since the room is always static and the background doesn't change, the best solution would be background subtraction algorithms, but they are quiet vulnerable to brightness changes, jolting, etc., so this way I cannot get clear and solid spots in place of humans in the room.

Do somebody has any clues on how to do that?

OpenCV version: 2.4.11

Comment: This question is too broad: people are still researching solutions to this problem. Try to be a little more specific

Comment: "the background doesn't change" the background does change (e.g. lighting). Please start reading some computer vision courses/books or start with simple tasks (e.g. static conditions)

Comment: How are you processing the image before trying to do the people detection ? Can you train a detector for your problem ? What programming language are you using ? python ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using OpenCV's implementation of [background subtractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html). It allows to specify a "history size" for estimating background. This tends to be more adaptive solution to smooth illumination changes.

Second thing use color components of a scene in you analysis. To do that convert colored images into Lab or HSV space and ignore either "L" or "V"  components.

Answer (score 0):

If the background gets changes over time, the best solution could be rolling-background model. It means we update the background over time based on the reference and current background (you can find more by google). From this point, we can use background subtraction.